# Can You Use a For Loop(s) to Optimize This Code?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script

I am hoping there is a cleaner way to write this code. What I have below works exactly as intended, however, I will have to do this for multiple different sections, so before I do that I am looking to see if there is a way potentially using for loops or something that would shorten this code and help it to run faster.

The user can enter a number of images from as few as 1 to as many as 4. Depending on the number they select, a new line is created for each image to be placed. This therefore pushes lines at the bottom of the spreadsheet that many lines lower, so this needs to be accounted for to ensure the information still gets inserted in the correct location regardless of how many images the user chooses. This is written in Google Apps Scripts within Google Sheets. If the value of the variables below is anything greater than 2, the user wants an image there, less than 3 they do not want an image and no new line will be created.

```
  var graphic1_loc = 'A62';
  var graphic2_loc = 'A63';
  var graphic3_loc = 'A64';
  var graphic4_loc = 'A65';
  var graphic5_loc = 'A66';

  var graphic1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+graphic1_loc).getValue();
  var graphic2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+graphic2_loc).getValue();
  var graphic3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+graphic3_loc).getValue();
  var graphic4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+graphic4_loc).getValue();
  var graphic5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+graphic5_loc).getValue();

  var website_loc = 'D2';      
  var website_placement = 'B47';
  var website_placement2 = 'B48';
  var website_placement3 = 'B49';
  var website_placement4 = 'B50';
      var website_placement5 = 'B51';

      if (graphic2.length < 3 && graphic3.length < 3 && graphic4.length < 3 && graphic5.length < 3) {
        var website = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+website_loc).getValue()
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Briefing!'+website_placement).setValue('For the latest forecast updates, visit ' + website+'.');
      }
      else if (((graphic2.length > 2) && (graphic3.length < 3) && (graphic4.length < 3) && (graphic5.length < 3)) ||
               +((graphic2.length < 3) && (graphic3.length > 2) && (graphic4.length < 3) && (graphic5.length < 3)) ||
               +((graphic2.length < 3) && (graphic3.length < 3) && (graphic4.length > 2) && (graphic5.length < 3)) ||
               +((graphic2.length < 3) && (graphic3.length < 3) && (graphic4.length < 3) && (graphic5.length > 2))) {
        var website = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+website_loc).getValue()
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Briefing!'+website_placement2).setValue('For the latest forecast updates, visit ' + website+'.');
      }
      else if ((graphic2.length > 2 && graphic3.length > 2 && graphic4.length < 3 && graphic5.length < 3) ||
               +(graphic2.length > 2 && graphic3.length < 3 && graphic4.length > 2 && graphic5.length < 3) ||
               +(graphic2.length > 2 && graphic3.length < 3 && graphic4.length < 3 && graphic5.length > 2) ||
               +(graphic2.length < 3 && graphic3.length > 2 && graphic4.length > 2 && graphic5.length < 3) ||
               +(graphic2.length < 3 && graphic3.length > 2 && graphic4.length < 3 && graphic5.length > 2) ||
               +(graphic2.length < 3 && graphic3.length < 3 && graphic4.length > 2 && graphic5.length > 2)) {
        var website = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+website_loc).getValue()
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Briefing!'+website_placement3).setValue('For the latest forecast updates, visit ' + website+'.');
      }
      else if (((graphic2.length > 2) && (graphic3.length > 2) && (graphic4.length > 2) && (graphic5.length < 3)) || 
               +((graphic2.length > 2) && (graphic3.length > 2) && (graphic4.length < 3) && (graphic5.length > 2)) ||
               +((graphic2.length > 2) && (graphic3.length < 3) && (graphic4.length > 2) && (graphic5.length > 2)) ||
               +((graphic2.length < 3) && (graphic3.length > 2) && (graphic4.length > 2) && (graphic5.length > 2))) {
        var website = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+website_loc).getValue()
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Briefing!'+website_placement4).setValue('For the latest forecast updates, visit ' + website+'.');
      }
      else if ((graphic2.length > 2) && (graphic3.length > 2) && (graphic4.length > 2) && (graphic5.length > 2)) {
        var website = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+website_loc).getValue()
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Briefing!'+website_placement5).setValue('For the latest forecast updates, visit ' + website+'.');
      }
```

Comment: In your script, it seems that the length of value is compared. For example, in your situation, are there the values for comparing except for the length of value? In your latest question, `yes`, `no` and URL were used as the values. I think that if this can be used for this question, the script will be simpler. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, that is the case here. I would also like to account for them deleting the contents of the cell entirely in addition. So any one that has `Yes`, `yes`, or the URL are ones that would generate the new rows, which would have to be accounted for.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are talking about code factorization. It really depends on how the `<` or `>` are aligned in your `if` statement, if there is not common pattern, you might just leave as what it is.

If it does, my very first attempt is probably refactor out the common `if` statement into a function, for example (your first `else if`),

```
else if (((graphic2.length > 2) && (graphic3.length < 3) && (graphic4.length < 3) && (graphic5.length < 3)) ||...)
```

generalize it to a function, since `graphic2,3,4,5` are used all the time,
create a array before the comparison

```
var graphic_arr = [graphic2.length, graphic3.length, graphic4.length, graphic5.length]
```

then create a condition function;

```
function condOne(arr1,arr2) {
  return arr1[0] > arr2[0] && arr1[1] > arr2[1] && arr1[2] > arr2[2] && arr1[3] > arr2[3]
}
```

then your original condition can become

```
else if (condOne(graphic_arr, [2,3,3,3]) ||...)
```

if there are really some common pattern everywhere and you can create and **reuse** others like `condTwo()` etc, you can end up something like

note: each condition function has different `<` and `>` in comparison

```
if (condOne(graphic_arr, [ 4 digits])) || condTwo(graphic_arr, [ 4 digits])) || .....) 
elseif (condThree(graphic_arr, [ new 4 digits]) || condTwo(graphic_arr, [another 4 digits]))
.....
```

The running speed depends on the amount of data you are consuming just based on your current code, the condition checking wouldn't matter a lot as long as it does your intent correctly.

Comment: Each condition can be used twice, but it sounds like it wouldn't really be worth rewriting it like that since it is only used one other time and likely wouldn't affect the speed much. I appreciate your response!

Comment: @hunter21188 as long as your current code functions correctly, you should be fine. Considering the process of refactor may causes some new bugs, people wouldn't do it until they have time to do optimization. Sometimes you just want to make your code a little bit nicer and cleaner.